# PyErr_Print to a file

Tags: python, c++

I'm trying to use Python from C++ code as described [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/extending/embedding.html).
I got a few questions about `PyErr_Print()` function.

1. Does it print to the same `stderr` as in the calling C++ program?
2. How to make it print to a file? (I cannot redirect `stderr` from command line, and I wouldn't like to use Boost)

Comment: Does "I cannot redirect stderr" mean you don't know how?

Comment: @usr2564301, no, it means that this code runs in a DLL that is loaded by external software that I cannot modify and that software is GUI, so no stderr for it.